# Using a c .a file installed by os in a cabal package?

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I want to add a foreign function defined in a static library (`.a`) file to
my cabal package. Specifically this is the `libSDL2_test2.a` distributed with 
libsdl2.

What is the correct and most portable way of doing so? Note that
the field `extra-libraries` only handles shared object (`.so`) files.

Comment: Can't you just use `c-sources`?

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov, Im not sure that solves my problem. The `.a` file in question is `SDL2_test.a` which is part of SDL2. Isnt c-sources only for c source files and not precompiled `.a` files?

Comment: @HaskellElephant I think Mikhail is suggesting distributing the source, not the precompiled library. After all, cabal is a build tool.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, Im not suggesting shipping the precompiled binary, just using the one installed on the system. Sorry that was a bit unclear...

Answer (score 3):

There are a few evils in the world that I tell my children to watch out for.  Placing pre-compiled binaries inside of a cabalized package is such a dark evil that I can't even bring myself to tell them - I just hope the issue never arises.

***The Best Solution***

If you want to distribute binaries then select the platform (operating system and architecture) of choice and make a binary distribution.  That usually means making .deb, .rpm, .msi, homebrew, or macports packages.

***An Alternative***

If you must place this monstrosity in the `.cabal` then Mikhail has the right idea.  You can specify `extra-source-files` in your `.cabal` file to distribute binaries.  This is exactly how the [`intel-aes` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intel-aes-0.2.1.1/intel-aes.cabal) allowed users to leverage AES-NI even before most compilers had support for the instruction.

Comment: He he, Good to know! However I should specify. The binary is `SDL2_test.a` and is distributed with libsdl2. It was never an option to ship the precompiled binary with the cabalized package.

Comment: @HaskellElephant In that case I'm having trouble understanding your question.  You probably know how to specify an FFI using the 'foreign' keyword.  Is the problem specifying linker arguments in the .cabal?  You can specify external libraries and GHC opts using .cabal or you can roll a more complex build system (Makefiles, Setup.hs, or something else) which can be called by cabal.

Comment: @ThomasMDubuisson, yes there is a lot of stuff you can do. However, one cannot link `.a` files with the `extra-libraries` field, I guess I could specify the link flag with the `ghc-flags` field , but I don't think ghci likes `.a` files at all.

Comment: This is the first time in the discussion that I've heard mention of ghci.

Comment: @ThomasMDubuisson, sorry for not adding that to the question, but I found out a lot later while trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: @ThomasMDubuisson  , so what I was able to figure out is that as you said, one can add the correct linker flags to the `ghc-flags` section, however, while testing this I found that if you do that, you cannot load the package into ghci. So it would seem that I am doing something wrong.